# I am new in CakePhp 3 and trying to make web service for login and got stuck?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, restful-authentication

This is my controller UsersController:

---

```
    <?php
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controller;
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function index() 
    {
        $this->autoRender=false;
        $data = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
        $data = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($data) : $data;
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $obj = json_decode($data);
        $requested_service = $obj->{"request_type_sent"};
            switch($requested_service)
            {
                case 'CONSUMER_SERVICE_LOGIN':


                    $consumerObj=new ConsumersController();

                    echo $consumerObj->checkConsumerLogin($obj->{"email"},$obj->{"password"});
                    unset($consumerObj);
                break;  
                default:
                echo "wrong"; 
                echo $requested_service;die;
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

This is my consumerController that have the login function:

---

```
     <?php
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controller;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
class ConsumersController extends AppController
{
    public function checkConsumerLogin($emailID,$password)
    {
        $users = TableRegistry::get('Users');
        $result = $users->query("call testing('".$emailID."','".$password."')");
        if($result)
            {
                foreach ($result as $row) 
                {
                    $returnArray=array();
                    $returnArray['id']=$row->id;
                    $returnArray['email'] = $row->email;
                    $returnArray['password'] = $row->password;  
                }
                $response=$returnArray;
        }
        return json_encode($response);
    }
    }
```

Here I have created stored procedure testing that check email and password

I am running it on postman and getting last record of table. i want to know is it the right way to write web services. i have a database for it and **UsersTable** model and the json data i send is:

---

```
{
    "request_type_sent":"CONSUMER_SERVICE_LOGIN",
    "email":"j@gmail.com",
    "password":"asdf"
}
```

### output in postman:

```
{"email":"k@gmail.com","password":"aaaa"}
```

my users table have three column id auto increment an primary key and other two are email and password.

I googled this but I found nothing, plz help me out.

Comment: is your cjson library working properly ?? if not you can use simply json_encode() , and json_decode() .

Comment: thanks i use json_encode() and json_decode() its work now but the thing is now my stored procedure returning all rows of table i don't know why? in phpmyadmin procedure working nicely.

Comment: $users = TableRegistry::get('Users');  

  $result = $users->query("CALL testing('".$emailID."','".$password."')");

when i am looping through $result it's give me all rows of table can you tell me why?
@swt_me

Comment: Your query looks so complicated , looks like you are avoiding cakephp's convention..so I am not sure but still you can try : $this->Users->query('first',);

Comment: Thanks for reply....i made a procedure name testing that have only one query to check email and password and accepted two parameters email and password , i just want that exact row??